# storing a reference/pointer to a std::set object

Tags: c++

I'm making a game about marbles which uses a struct to describe the marble properties:

```
struct Marble
{
Color color;
int weight;
//Other customizable marble properties
};
```

I am currently using a `std::vector` to keep track of which marbles are at which position on the game board:

```
std::vector<Marble> m_marbles;
```

At any time, I can check the properties of a marble given its position by indexing into the vector. To check the color of the marble in position 20:

```
m_marbles[20].color;
```

The user can create custom marbles and add them to the game board. If I want to add a new marble to the game board, I create a new struct object and push it onto the vector:

```
Marble m;

//Fill struct with marble information

m_marbles.push_back(m)
```

The problem is that the game board is very large (many thousands of marbles) and many of the marbles are exactly the same.

Let's say there are 4000 positions on the game board. Maybe 3000 of those are red marbles with a weight of 1.0. In the current solution, 3000 equivalent Marble objects are taking up space in my vector.

Since the user can define his own marble types, I can't just hard code all of the possible marble types and then have the vector store a pointer to the appropriate marble object.

I was thinking about using a `std::set` to store the different marble types. Then, when the user goes to create his custom marble he can try to insert it into the set. If the same type of marble already exists, it won't waste memory.

My question is, how can I store a reference into the `std::set`? For example, let's say my set consists of these marble types:

```
{RedMarble, BlueMarble, StrangeMarble, ConfusedMarble}
```

Now I want to assign a red marble to position 20 on the game board:

```
m_marbles[20] = ?
```

I also want to check the color of the marble at position 31:

```
m_marble[31].color;
```

Is it possible to work with a set in this way? The find and insert functions return iterators but won't those become invalidated if I insert more items into the set?

Comment: Looks to me like you don't want a set. You probably want a vector, or even just an array.

Comment: Are you more concerned with memory footprint or performance?  Picking one of these will determine which solution is best for you.

Comment: @Dave - a vector of Marble*? How would I be sure that only one of each distinct type of marble exists (and is taking up memory) without a set?

Comment: @Chad - The performance is a problem since the game board is expandable. Imagine having 300,000 Marble objects when 150,000 of them contain identical data. The problem of using a vector of Marble* is that if the type of Marble already exists, I need a way to get a pointer to it. If it doesn't exist, I can `new` a new Marble object and add it to the list of unique Marble types.

Comment: [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (and other spatial indexes) are tangential but perhaps interesting to you if you actually have 300K marble scenarios and want to test for collisions and such...nifty web demo: http://lab.polygonal.de/?p=202

Comment: Store a shared pointer in the set and reference it in the marbles vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you are trying to do. You can store pointers in your vector, which pointers point to the Marbles in your set. Or you can store iterators in your vector, again which iterators point to Marbles in your set.

Here is how I would do it with pointers:

```
// A useful helper funtction -- not required, but useful.
const Marble* Helper(const Marble& m) {
  static std::set<Marble> uniqueMarbles;
  return &*(uniqueMarbles.insert(m).first);
}

// A vector of pointers to marbles
std::vector<const Marble*> m_marbles;

// You can pass temporaries to the helper function, and it returns a permanent pointer
m_marbles.push_back(Helper(Marble(RED, 1.0));

Marble m;
m.setColor(BLUE);
m_marbles.push_back(Helper(m));


// You can reference your marbles
Color c = m_marbles[i]->getColor();

// Hopefully the following will produce a compiler error message
m_marbles[i]->setColor(GREEN); // Oops, m_marbles holds const pointers
```

Comment: Is the address of an element in a std::set guaranteed to stay the same? I thought that maybe as the set grew, it might have to reallocate memory similar to a vector.

Comment: Asking because I'm wondering if it's possible to store the address of &(*first) in my vector without having to look up the element every time.

Comment: The address of the elements of `std::set` are guaranteed to stay the same until you erase the item or destroy the set.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the vector contain *pointers* to Marble structures:

```
std::vector<Marble*> m_marbles;
```

A pointer doesn't take up much space and you can still use `Marble` as a base class.

Comment: A vector of Marble* is ideal but the problem is duplicating the same type of marble. When the user goes to create a new marble, I can't just create a new one via `new` and store a pointer to it. I need to check that the type of marble doesn't already exist. If that type of marble doesn't already exist I can create a new Marble object and store a pointer to that. If it does already exist, I just want to store a pointer to the existing Marble object. I thought that a `std::set` would be ideal since it doesn't allow duplicate objects.

Answer (score 0):

If the game board is really just a few thousand places large, I wouldn't care about wasting space. For example

```
10000 places * sizeof(Marble) = 10000 * 100 bytes ~ 1 MB
```

Not a big amount of memory by today's standards.

If it might grow very large, then you can indeed store your unique Marbles in a set and reference them with a pointer, as @BenRuijl already has shown.

Comment: Well, the game board is expandable so it could grow very large. As more and more marbles get added to the game board, it eats up more and more memory for no reason since the structs contain identical data.

Answer (score 0):

Build a class `Marble` containing a pointer to a `MarbleType` defining the properties of each marble (for each sort of marble you have one instance of `MarbleType`). The vector may contain `Marble`s or shared pointers to `Marble`s or unique pointers. If the `Marble` class is small (flyweight pattern), you do not waste space, but nevertheless have a clean and flexible solution. The marble types could be named (e.g. by a string) and be stored in a `std::map`.